# SMTP settings for Office 365 in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, office365

I have an Office 365 mail account with Godaddy. I'm trying to setup the SMTP settings for my Rails app:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.office365.com",
:port                 => 587,
:user_name            => ENV["OFFICE_USERNAME"],
:password             => ENV["OFFICE_PASSWORD"],
:authentication       => 'login',
:domain               => 'example.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

but when I test those settings by submitting a message from my contact page, I get this error message:

> 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

How to set up the SMTP settings for an Office 365 account in a Rails application?

Comment: I did the Office 365 setup as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78222246/3813331

Answer (score 20):

I found the answer to this question here:
http://www.brownwebdesign.com/blog/connecting-rails-to-microsoft-exchange-smtp-email-server

Relevant parts:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.office365.com',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name      => ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'congrueit.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Then:

make sure the from: email address matches, from domain, and user/pass.

Not my work just copy and paste of relevant information that worked for me.

**Addition for 2021**:
Since April 2020, you have to enable SMTP AUTH in your office 336 organisation **and** the mail account you are using.
See [Enable ... SMPT AUTH at docs.ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission). In this document, the explanation is missing that both parts must be enabled.

Comment: Great, but you should write the relevant parts in your answer to prevent losing information in case that link doesn't work one day.

Comment: You solved my problem for using msmtp with Godaddy 365 SMTP, thanks!

Comment: I found this useful, thank you.
but I think the domain part is irrelevant here.

Comment: I can confirm that the domain part is irrelevant. At least it's not needed when it's included in the user_name.