# Rails actionmailer, gmail works, office 365 does not.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, office365

I've got Actionmailer sending emails using gmail with the following settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => "gmail.com",
   :user_name => "user_name@gmail.com",
   :password => "password",
   :authentication => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

However, I can't get office 365 mail to work, I have the following settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.office365.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "my_domain.com",
    :user_name => "username@my_domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    :password => "password",
    :authentication => :login, 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

If I try and send an email with this client I get:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError
550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve the problem? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what I found was this was an internal IT issue, and nothing was wrong with my code - they just hadn't set permissions correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out microsoft requires the same email for both the `smtp_settings` and the `:from` field in `emailer.rb`.

Comment: any reference to above answer?

Comment: I changed the from in app/mailers/application_mailer.rb, and that did it. And like always, never forget to reset the rails server when testing!

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue with Gmail and Office365, after scratching head for many hours I find out solution.

If you are using Office365 account for sending emails, it only works if `user_name` and `sender_address` and same value. i.e

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.office365.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'my_domain.pk',
    user_name:            'noreply@my_domain.pk',
    password:             ENV['PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'login',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  email: {
    deliver_with:         :deliver,
    email_prefix:         '[Email Prefix]',
    sender_address:       %{<noreply@my_domain.pk>},
    exception_recipients: %w{abc@gmail.com}
  }

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

> **Key Point:** So keeping following values same worked for me

```
user_name: 'noreply@my_domain.pk' 

sender_address: %{<noreply@my_domain.pk>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more on sending with SMTP through Office 365 over here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323.aspx

With the authentication method like this you don't need to set :domain.

Answer (score 0):

In `devise.rb` I set `"no-reply@******.com"`, and I mentioned at `production.rb` in smtp setting as `"noreply@*****.com"`.

After replace the email id in `devise.rb` as `"no-reply@*******.com"` with `"noreply@******.com"`, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Mailer to use Office 365 (`config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.office365.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               ENV.fetch("APP_MAILER_DOMAIN"),    # Your domain
    user_name:            ENV.fetch("APP_MAILER_USERNAME"),  # Your Office 365 email address
    password:             ENV.fetch("APP_MAILER_PASSWORD"),  # Your Office 365 password
    authentication:       'login',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Now you need to disable authenticated client SMTP submission (SMTP AUTH) in Exchange Online:

1. Sign in to the [Microsoft Entra admin](https://entra.microsoft.com/) center as at least a Security Administrator.
2. Browse to Identity > Overview > **Properties**.
3. Select Manage security defaults.
4. Set Security defaults to **Disabled**.
5. Select Save.

Now the mailer should work for you. NOTE: as you have disabled default security settings, you need to make sure you have your custom security policies in place to protect your organization.

Additional resource to read regarding security settings:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/security-defaults